# Copying a Partition-Time it Could Take

Tags: partitioning, time, partition-copy

I'm in the process of copying all the partitions of a hard drive to another with gparted to another one as so that I can simply pop the new drive in mn.y computer and start it up, I was wondering if anybody knows the average time it takes to copy a drive bit by bit in a gig/time ratio, as the drive is 160 gigs, the boot partition is 70 gigs, data is 70 and the rest being the pqservice partition, and oh my my monitor just turned off during the copying of the boot partition yet the the computer seems to still be running fine, any words on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the speed of both drives, but a gigabyte per minute is a good ballpark figure.

Comment: So hour at bare minimum, thanks, mind you I'm wondering if it's actually copying right now as the monitor turned off while copying yet the drives are still running and the indicator lights are still pulsing at the same rate.

Comment: It's probably your power management stuff. Try hitting the control key and see if it comes back on.

Comment: Thank you, to be honest, I was quite worried there for a moment.

Comment: As it took, the first partition only took 40 minutes.

Comment: Another quick question if you know the answer, in gparted the PQservice partition has a exclamation mark next to it, wondering why that is, haven't copied it over yet or at least tried, waiting for the data partition to copy, but wondering if you knew why.

Comment: Well just found out gparted doesn't do a true bit by bit copy of partitions as the data partition that only had 3 gigs of data in it took less than 2 minutes to copy, so it skips empty sectors, any ideas on what to use to copy the partition including empty sectors as to attempt to recover deleted data.

Comment: I would boot a Linux distribution and use `dd` to do a raw binary read of the partition.

Comment: I would do that but to be honest, I'm your average computer if I had a walkthrough guide/how to I could probably do it, if you know of any I might just be able to save the information.